# Issue installing Hugo dependencies with Brew in OSX. SSL alert protocol version

Tags: github, openssl, homebrew, hugo

I've updated brew and openssl, but I continue to get the following error when running `brew install hugo`:

```
MyMac:temp MyUser$ brew install hugo
Updating Homebrew...
==> Downloading https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/archive/v0.53.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/MyUser/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/98345eef182a35281fb597a40ad17badc1bd1566127fb3eadd309204db690975--hugo-0.53.tar.gz
==> go build -o /usr/local/Cellar/hugo/0.53/bin/hugo -tags extended main.go
Last 15 lines from /Users/MyUser/Library/Logs/Homebrew/hugo/01.go:
    fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/eknkc/amber/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
go: github.com/nfnt/resize@v0.0.0-20180221191011-83c6a9932646: git fetch -f https://github.com/nfnt/resize refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /Users/MyUser/Library/Caches/Homebrew/go_cache/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3c41db3334414b5559791060aadeb7b9a9cd6323146d18c88ea1134dabc06c55: exit status 128:
    fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/nfnt/resize/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

But, when I attempt to access any of the dependencies directly nothing goes wrong...

```
MyMac:temp MyUser$ git clone https://github.com/nfnt/resize.git
Cloning into 'resize'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 466, done.
remote: Total 466 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 466
Receiving objects: 100% (466/466), 123.19 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (263/263), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Versions

```
MyMac:temp MyUser$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018

MyMac:temp MyUser$ brew -v
Homebrew 1.8.6

MyMac:temp MyUser$ git --version
git version 2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)
```

Do I have any other options?

Comment: Am I allowed to bump content?

Comment: Are you able to connect to https://github.com using `openssl s_client`? Are you sure that *brew* uses the system *OpenSSL* libs?

Comment: I assume so. I deleted my Homebrew caches and ran `brew install hugo`. The github portion of that worked fine.

`Updating Homebrew...
==> Downloading https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/archive/v0.53.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://codeload.github.com/gohugoio/hugo/tar.gz/v0.53
######################################################################## 100.0%
`

Answer (score 0):

Check first the output of `brew doctor`.

As [seen here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/273568), forcing the re-installation of `openssl` might help

```
cd /usr/bin
rm -r openssl
brew install openssl
brew update && brew upgrade
```

If not, similar to [this issue](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew/issues/557#issuecomment-432448533), you could first try and install a newer `curl` and build a newer `git` that uses newer libraries than the system provides:

```sh
brew reinstall curl
brew link --force curl
brew reinstall --build-from-source git
brew update
```

Make sure `which curl` and `which git` should return `/usr/local/bin/curl` and `/usr/local/bin/git`.